# Neo4J.rb & Carrierwave-neo4j — File upload error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, carrierwave

About two weeks ago I try to provide file uploading in my rails application with Neo4J.rb and reu / carrierwave-neo4j. And it works properly. But now it's crashed.

When I fill file field the error are appeared:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown property type on: #ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x17003a2, class org.jruby.RubyObject

app/controllers/q_resources_controller.rb:47:in create'
app/controllers/q_resources_controller.rb:45:increate'
```

Code of _form view:

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= image_tag(@q_resource.bfile_url) if @q_resource.bfile? %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :bfile_cache %>
      <%= f.file_field :bfile %>
      <label>
        <%= f.check_box :remove_bfile %>
        Remove bfile
      </label>
    </div>
```

Code of my controller is:

```
45: Neo4j::Transaction.run do
46: @q_resource = QResource.new(params[:q_resource])
47: @q_resource.save!
```

But I try to upload file manually and it's successfull (if dont's fill file field):

```
Neo4j::Transaction.run do
@q_resource = QResource.new()
@q_resource.bfile = File.open("D:/Kirill.jpg")
@q_resource.save!
```

QResource model is:

```
class QResource < Neo4j::Rails::Model
property :title, :type => String
index :title, :type => :fulltext

property :description, :type => String
index :description, :type => :fulltext

property :body, :type => String
index :body, :type => :fulltext

property :position, :type => Fixnum
index :position

property :url, :type => String
index :url

property :note, :type => String
index :note, :type => :fulltext

property :isource, :type => String
index :isource, :type => :fulltext

property :created_at, :type => DateTime
index :created_at

property :updated_at, :type => DateTime
index :updated_at

property :bfile, :type => String
mount_uploader :bfile, BinfileUploader
end
```

I only updated gems and don't work on "upload part" of my application.
It seems like error while Neo4j try to parse hash with multipart data... Maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of neo4j.rb are you using ?
It could be a bug that has been fixed.
See this http://groups.google.com/group/neo4jrb/browse_thread/thread/a1fa5f675491da68
and the issue http://neo4j.lighthouseapp.com/projects/15548-neo4j/tickets/201-neo4jcarrierwave-neo4j-file-upload-error